# JaVers, SpringDatat, JPA: Querying for Entity Update inside a Collection

Tags: jpa, spring-data, javers

I'm new to Stackoverflow, so I will make my best to conforms with usage. I was wondering if there were a way to get a complete list of changes/snapshots of a given Entity. For now it works well with edition of Singular Properties, as well as Addition and Deletion to Collection Property. But I'm unable to find when a Child Entity in the Collection Property was updated.

Given two Entities, and a LinkEntity:

```
@Entity
class Person {
  @Id
  Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  Set<LinkAddress> addresses;
}

@Entity
class Address {
  @Id
  Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
  Set<Address> persons;
}

@Entity
class LinkPersonAddress {
  @Id
  Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @ShallowReference
  Person person;

  @ManyToOne
  @ShallowReference
  Address address;

  String linkType;
}
```

My use case is following. I get a specific Person by Id #1, and then mutate the type of specific Address (ie. HOME --> WORK). I save the Person back with the modified Set and let JPA Cascade my changes. Although all Spring Data Repositories for Person, Address, and LinkPersonAddress are annotated with @JaversSpringDataAuditable, I cannot retrieve this "update" using Javers QueryBuilder with the class Person and Id #1. It makes sense as I should query the class LinkPersonAddress instead, but how can I specify that I want only the changes from LinkPersonAddress relevant to Person with Id #1.

PS: Please apologize any typos in code snippets, as I didn't write it in my Dev Environment.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the mapping. You did it wrong, Address is a classical ValueObject (see https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/#value-object) not Entity. Because:

- Address doesn't have its own identity (primary key genereted by a db sequence doesn't count)
- Address is owned by the Person Entity. Person with its Addresses forms the Aggregate.

When you correct the mapping, you can use ChildValueObjects filter, see https://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#child-value-objects-filter

Comment: I hear you, but probably my example (which is not my real use case) was not good enough. Let's assume we have Students, Courses, and a LinkTable with a type (Auditor, Enrolled) instead. I would like to have complete history for a given Course (with all update to the course properties), and somehow aggregate a complete history for a given Student inclusive Enrollments. So are you saying the LinkTable itself should be ValueObject, even if from JPA perspective it must be annotated with @Entity? Shall the JPA Annotation with a Custom ValueObject Mapping when first configuring Javers?

Comment: I tried a bit further in the direction you suggested, making my Link a Value Object, but then I tried to update a Student that had two Courses, Course#1 as Auditor and Course#2 as Enrolled. I wanted to switch the 2nd Link to Auditor, and I got, as Change, ValueRemoved (oldLink) and ValueAdded (newLink) each referring a different globalId, although I only updated the Link (JPA Id remained stable). I would think my Link has its own identity although "owned" by its Parent. Are we in an hybrid situation?

Comment: In Javers queries (JQL), there are no fully-fledged joins between Entities. What you can do, is to join child ValueObjects to its owning Entity using ChildValueObjects filter.
Another option is Shadow query, see https://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#query-for-shadows
Shadow query with scope COMMIT, can do Entity joins, but there are some limitations. I'm going to write a small article to show how it works

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I did send you a patch with a live example for another issue (558), I will try to extend it showing you what I mean here. Maybe then you'll get a chance to show me your suggestion, and why not make a little tutorial out of the example with Courses and Students...